# Print/Save complete Laravel Artisan Command output(large array from debug line) to file

Tags: php, laravel, file-io, command, laravel-artisan

I am working in Laravel 6.x project, where I have added debug line inside an Artisan command to get the large array generated from that line into text file as output.

It looks almost like following code in the `handle` method of said command:

```
....
if(!$dataArray->isEmpty())
{
    foreach ($dataArr as $dataEle)
    {
        $dataArrToPrnt[] = $dataEle->toArray();
        ....
    }
}
die(var_dump($dataArrToPrnt));
....
```

But the problem is the `dataArray` is huge, so after few entries, the command output skips the rest of the data and prints `(...more elements)` instead.

And I am running the command like below for printing to file(Windows 10 x64 with GitBash, so I have use php.exe instead of php):

```
php.exe artisan command-namespace:command >> result.out
```

How can I override/avoid that from happening and print the complete `dataArray` to file regardless of it's size ?

Comment: Have you looked at Lazy collection https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#lazy-collection-methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the global Log. Add a logging channel to your config/logging.php file like so:

```
'dataLogger' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/data.log'),
    'level' => 'info',
],
```

And use in your code like:

```
use Log; 
foreach ($dataArr as $dataEle){
    Log::channel('dataLogger')->info($dataEle);
}
```

(Or however you'd like to format your data.)